# ISNULL Not working when I am calculating the sum of two columns in the expression part of the function

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use `ISNULL ()`, but in the expression part of the function, instead of having a column name as the argument,I have the sum of four columns, and it should return a 0 when all of the value in the column is NULL, else the sum. for e.g., if three columns have values and corresponding value in the other column is Null, it should still return the sum of the three values. This is how I have written my query:

```
Select ISNULL([FY18 P1]+[FY18 P2]+[FY18 P3]+[FY18 P4],0) as [Previous YTD]
from TableA
```

This calculated column inside the ISNULL function is not working. Can anybody help me rewrite this expression so that it will work. What i mean when it is not working is that, it is returning a NULL when only one column is NULL but the rest of the columns have a value. Basically it should return the sum and not NULL in this case.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What do you mean by "is not working"? The code you posted should work for the requirements you stated.

Comment: If any of those columns _IS NULL_ then it will returrn 0 no matter what is the value of other columns, mybe you are looking to use `ISNULL()` function for each column.

Comment: "Not working" will not help us help you.  Now working how???  No result???  Wrong result???  Error out???

Comment: _it should return a 0 whenever one of the value in the column is NULL else the sum_ Well your query will do that unless you have something else you want to tell us about it.

Comment: , @SeanLange, when I mean the query is not working what I mean is that it is returning a NULL Value when all the columns are NULL, but when One column has a value(different from NULL) and when the other columns are NULL, I want to return that value but instead it is returning a NULL.

Comment: How do I remove the hold on this question? The solution posted is working and I have also edited the question for everybody else to understand the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any column in your concatenation `IS NULL` then the result will be `NULL`.

You need to wrap each column in `IS NULL` to make this column value 0 so that your addition doesn't return `NULL`.

```
SELECT ISNULL([FY18 P1],0) +ISNULL([FY18 P2],0) + ISNULL([FY18 P3],0) + ISNULL([FY18 P4],0)
```

This is because *anything* + `NULL` returns `NULL`

```
select 1 + 2 + 3 + NULL --returns `NULL`
```

Comment: From the OP question: _it should return a 0 whenever one of the value in the column is NULL else the sum..._ Does your solution met with his conditions?

Comment: Actually after re-reading it @Sami it does. *it should return a 0 whenever one of the value in the column is NULL*. Wrapping the column with `ISNULL` would return 0 when one value in the *column* is `NULL`. So, this answer is what they want.

Comment: @scsimon, Let me try your solution and see if that work. Thanks Sami as well for the quick response. what I am looking for is it should return the sum even if there is a null value in one column, and zero or Null when all the columns are NULL. Right now with my code, it is returning Null when one of the columns is NULL. Hope you guys understood the problem clearly.

Comment: @scsimon, your solution is working. Thanks Dude!!

Comment: @sami, thanks for the quick responses. this solution is returning the sum.

Comment: You're welcome @jishnusathyan good luck!